# Angular Scope and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

**My question in short**

how do i manipulate the isolated scope created by ng-repeat inside of my controller?

**To read the full problem i am having continue reading below:**

I have a collection on timelines and each of them further has a collection of captures (essentially images).

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="timeline in timelines | filter:search | orderBy:'event_date':sort">
        <ul ng-if="timeline.captures">
            <li ng-repeat="captures in timeline.captures | limitTo:imageLimit">
                <img ng-src="<% captures.capture_location %>">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a ng-click="(imageLimit = imageLimit + 1)">Load more</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

1. I want to limit the number of images being loaded on page load.. which i am able to do using `limitTo`
2. I want to load more images when the user clicks on 'Load more'. I am also able to do this by `ng-click="(imageLimit = imageLimit + 1)`

What i want to do:

I want to extract this out as a function

```
so that the following
<a href="#" ng-click="(imageLimit = imageLimit + 1)">Load more</a>
becomes 
<a href="#" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</a>
```

To achieve this, i tried the following:

inside my controller

```
$scope.imageLimit = 1; // number of images to show initially on page load

$scope.loadMore = function() {
    $scope.imageLimit += 1;
};
```

Now what is happening is that this this not create the `imageLimit` model inside the repeated scope (if you understand what i mean) but instead creates the `imageLimit` model at the controller scope. This is also the expected behaviour but i want to know how do i manipulate the scope within the repeated timeline (isolated scope for that timeline) inside my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to `loadMore()` for each timeline, independantly of the other ones. The `loadMore()` function should thus take the timeline as argument, and the limit should be a property of the timeline:

```
angular.forEach($scope.timelines, function(timeline) {
    timeline.imageLimit = 10; // default value
});

$scope.loadMore(timeline) {
    timeline.imageLimit++;
}
```

And in your template:

```
<li ng-repeat="captures in timeline.captures | limitTo:timeline.imageLimit">
...
<a ng-click="loadMore(timeline)">Load more</a>
```

Comment: thank you. worked perfect.. more important that i learned how to tackle such a problem.